# Correlationships between food choice and personality

Tags: personality, feeding

There are known attempts to correlate the personality of an individual with their choice of a color or a shape - something which I have asked about [here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/19510/establishing-personality-from-shape-and-color-preferences) and am using in an app that I am delveoping.  I am now starting to ask myself whether there are any formal studies that attempt to correlate common food choices with personality.  I have come across a few useful ideas by simply googling for "food choice and personality".  e.g. [Keller & Siegrist (2015)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.appet.2014.10.003). and [Zayed (n.d.)](https://www.consumerhealthdigest.com/general-health/food-choices-and-eating-habits-says-your-personality.html)

However, neither of those articles to my mind comes close to being a formal study of the subject.  In the context of my own app I am wondering whether I can augment its understanding of its user by adding - to an existing list of personality acquisition questions - a request to select from, say, images that show

- A burger
- An apple
- A chocolate bar
- A chili pepper

Given that I am using many other personality assessment measures I would imagine that even without any known prior art on the subject I will in due course be able to glean something useful from an answer here.  However, I would be most grateful to anyone who might be able to point me to any formal, peer-reviewed studies on the subject.

**References**

Keller, C., & Siegrist, M. (2015). Does personality influence eating styles and food choices? Direct and indirect effects. *Appetite*, 84, 128-138.
DOI: [10.1016/j.appet.2014.10.003](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.appet.2014.10.003) PMID: [25308432](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25308432)

Zayed, A. (n.d.) *What Your Food Choices and Eating Habits Say about Your Personality?* Retreivable from: https://www.consumerhealthdigest.com/general-health/food-choices-and-eating-habits-says-your-personality.html

Comment: [Zayed (n.d.)](https://www.consumerhealthdigest.com/general-health/food-choices-and-eating-habits-says-your-personality.html) linked to [Miller (2013)](http://www.ift.org/newsroom/news-releases/2013/july/17/personality-spicy-foods.aspx) - an Institute for Food Technologists article which states that personality may predict if you like spicy foods.  Does that not help with chilli peppers?

Comment: I just found the source article for Miller (2013).  It is Byrnes, N. K., & Hayes, J. E. (2013). Personality factors predict spicy food liking and intake. *Food quality and preference*, 28(1), 213-221. doi: [10.1016/j.foodqual.2012.09.008](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.foodqual.2012.09.008)

Comment: @ChrisRogers Interesting paper...statistical methodology was terrible though. I wouldn't believe a word they say without any confirmation, except the result with Sensation Seeking. They have a major major [jelly bean problem](https://xkcd.com/882/) and make terrible statistical conclusions (i.e., p=.06 no effect! p=0.05 wow an effect!)

Comment: @BryanKrause you could use the paper as the start of a negatory answer claiming there isn't much to infer and showing how food choices has more to do with some other factor

Comment: Why is that first paper not a "formal study of the subject" in your view?

Comment: I'm inclined to put this question on hold; typing in ***food choice and personality*** in Google Scholar yields a page full of correlational study, among 800k+ other hits. By far most of those will be irrelevant, but it does indicate an existence of a huge body of literature on the topic. Consider Google Scholar or related academic search engines, specify your question and we would be glad seeing your refined question(s) appear here. For now, I'm voting to close (which is binding I'm afraid)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad for the scope of this site; a Google Scholar search yield thousands of hits. Libraries can be filled on this question.